# Failure to connect to Luxonis Oak-D through Docker

Tags: docker, opencv, roboflow, luxonis

I'm trying to get a Luxonis camera to run a custom model. I have been successful at running the  Luxonis depthai examples on a virtual environment on my computer (MacBook Pro) with the Oak-D. I was also able to create a model "Oak-D ball detection" that does a pretty good job at identifying balls. I was able to check this in the example web app and it works well enough.

However, I cannot seem to deploy it to the Luxonis camera. Following Roboflow's steps in my virtual environment (https://docs.roboflow.com/inference/luxonis-oak#using-the-oak-inference-api), I make it to step 4, "run the server with the following command.” I think it doesn’t like this because when I go to http://localhost:9001/validate the webpage says: "OAK device connection not validated, follow docs.roboflow.com to debug: No available devices.” This seems strange since I am able to run example code.

How do I remedy this? I do not see anything in the documentation about the OAK device failing to connect.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience if you can run Luxonis example python scripts, then the Luxonis docker finds the device as well...

As an interim step, you could make sure their docker runs on your host

```
docker pull luxonis/depthai-library
docker run --rm \
    --privileged \
    -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb \
    --device-cgroup-rule='c 189:* rmw' \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    luxonis/depthai-library:latest \
    python3 /depthai-python/examples/rgb_preview.py
```